# Eloquent subQuery fails with known field

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, subquery

I try this query:

```
        $invoice =  Invoice::query()
        ->select([
            'invoices.id',
            'invoices.created_at',
            'invoices.start_date',
            'invoices.end_date',
            'agencies.name as agency',
            'agencies.address',
            'agencies.zipcode',
            'agencies.phone',
            'consumers.name as consumer',
            'consumers.addresses',
            'invoice_items.amount as total',
            'billings.hours',
            'billings.rate',
            'billings.amount',
        ])
        ->addSelect(['agency_address' => \App\Models\City::select('address')
            ->whereColumn('cities.zipcode', 'agencies.zipcode')
            ->first()->address])
        ->leftJoin('agencies', 'agencies.id', 'invoices.agency_id')
        ->leftJoin('cities', 'cities.zip', 'agencies.zipcode')
        ->leftJoin('invoice_items', 'invoice_items.invoice_id', 'invoices.id')
        ->leftJoin('billings', 'billings.id', 'invoice_items.billing_id')
        ->leftJoin('consumers', 'consumers.id', 'billings.consumer_id')
        ->find($id);
```

But it fails with:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'agencies.zipcode' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `address` from
> `v_cities` where `v_cities`.`zipcode` = `agencies`.`zipcode` limit 1)

This field is included in the main select and it returns data just fine without the addSelect method.
What might be the reason?

Comment: why not add a new attribute in select clause as `cities.address` instead of `addSelect`

Comment: Valid observation Khalid! On this case it's easier that way. I got carried away on getting aggregates and having this error and not posting exactly that particular situation. Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: So if you still have issues with the aggregated query you can update your question and add relevant details